# how to have chef upgrade a package if it exists and install it if it doesn't?

Tags: chef-infra

it seems like setting

```
action :upgrade
```

will only work if the package is already installed? (Total chef newb so forgive me if I'm mistaken about this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:upgrade` will install the package if it's not installed. Go ahead and use it, you should be fine.